# How many other people like me know the only way to FULLY understand the OT and NT is by being able to read the original language?

Tags: language, bible

Just by reading different versions of the OT and NT how easy it is in one language to get some sentences misinterpreted so that leads to to think after the Bible has been written in almost EVERY language in the world within more than 2000 yrs. How much more have the words been lost, misinterpreted, as well as lost some very important meaning to those words that we don't have words to "fit" into some of the original words that the Bible was originally written in. So my question is why should we have to pay to learn to read or be made to become a scholar in order to have the opportunity to read word for word what the Bible actually reads? Why wasn't our parents,us,our children,their children,our grandparents,ect.,ect taught in school how to read this very seemingly important document that WE ALL SHOULD HAVE THE OPPORTUNITY to read for ourselves what OUR BIBLE really says WITHOUT having to PAY a lot of money in order to be able to READ what AND HOW OUR BIBLE REALLY IS SUPPOSED TO BE READ AND MEAN? I mean most countries around the world don't have to pay to be taught in their schools how to read,write,or speak English and/or Spanish SO WHY DO ONLY PEOPLE WITH MONEY GET TO Have THE OPPORTUNITY to read the original Bible in it's original language when in my opinion is something so detrimental in our spiritual development as a child of GOD WE SHOULD ALL HAVE THE RIGHT TO BE TAUGHT HOW TO READ OUR FATHER VERY VERY VERY IMPORTANT BOOK

Comment: Welcome to BH and thanks for joining in. Your important question is about how society prepares, or fails to prepare, people to read the Bible. On this site we look at the Bible itself and not at society, so in its present form your question is not right for this site.

Comment: In the age of internet, we don't need to spend any money for books, God provide freely.

Comment: I would class the above as a 'rant' not a serious question, myself. The capitals give it away, which is usually a sign that the writer would like to SHOUT (if they could) rather than courteously present a considered argument.

Comment: I agree with NigelJ.

Answer (score 2):

"SO WHY DO ONLY PEOPLE WITH MONEY GET TO Have THE OPPORTUNITY"

There are many online resources to read the Bible in it's original form. Some of them are:

- [BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/)
- [Blue Letter Bible](https://www.blueletterbible.org/)

Comment: Those have interlinear they are of no use for anyone who isn't learning Original languages.

Comment: I disagree with the first comment in this thread. Although Original Greek/Hebrew learners may have an edge here, I am arguing that the interlinear mentioned in this answer are still helpful to amateur Bible scholars.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't pay any money, I just downloaded the e-books for free, and used the free version of Duolingo, and within a couple of months I learned all the basics of Greek. Start with John Dobson's [book](http://bakerpublishinggroup.com/books/learn-new-testament-greek-3rd-edition/110/students/esources/themes/60) on NT Greek. However, learning Greek helps us interpret the Bible no more than knowing English makes one understand the English Bible. It has very little benefit, only for the in-depth details which go beyond the translations and commentaries. You should focus on the literature and its context to interpret the text in your own language, that is sufficient.